# Using np.diag() to construct a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

The standard usage of the `np.diag(a)` function when given a 1D array `a` is to create a 2D array with the diagonal entries being the elements of `a`. In my case, `a` is a 2D array with size n x m. My goal is to generate an n x n x m array in a manner similar to the `np.diag()` function, where each n x n slice is a matrix of zeros with the m'th row of `a` in the diagonal. What is the best way of doing this? Clearly it can be done with the `np.diag()` function and a `for` loop, but I am wondering whether a vectorized version of this exists with numpy.

Comment: I think so - am I understanding correctly that my desired matrix can be obtained by multiplying this identity matrix by `a`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use the function `np.broadcast_to`, which broadcasts a given array to a new shape.  I had trouble broadcasting the `m` dimension to the end of the array, but broadcasting it as the first dimension and then transposing along the first and last dimensions also seemed to work just fine.

Please see the code snippet below:

```
# Specify dimensions
n = 4
m = 3

# Create diagonal matrix
D = np.eye(n) 

# Broadcast diagonal and transpose
B = np.transpose(np.broadcast_to(D, (m,) + D.shape), (2, 1, 0))

# Verify shape
print(B.shape)
--> (4, 4, 3)

# Verify correct slice
print(B[:, :, 0])
--> array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 1., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Hope this helps!